# PHP built-in SOAP passing parameters

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am ridiculously frustrated with PHP's built-in SOAP client.  It seems like every post I read on the internet suggests every variation of code I've tried should work, but none of them do.  This is the current state of a simplified version of my code, but the have been MANY MANY others.

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("uReachWebServices.wsdl", array(
    "trace"        => true,
    "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2,
));
$auth       = array(
    "PartnerId" => "hidden_from_StackOverflow",
    "Password"  => "hidden_from_StackOverflow",
);

$parameters = array(
    phoneNumber => array("PIN" => "XXXX", "_" = "XXXXXXXXXXX"),
);

$header = new SoapHeader("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope", "Authentication", (object) $auth, false);
$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($header);

try {
    $soapClient->GetMailboxInfo((object) $parameters);
} catch (SoapFault $ex) {
    ChromePhp::error($ex->getMessage());
    ChromePhp::log($ex->getTraceAsString());
}

ChromePhp::log($soapClient->__getLastRequest());
ChromePhp::log($soapClient->__getLastResponse());
```

I'm trying to get the following output for the parameters...

```
<phoneNumber ns1:PIN="XXXX">XXXXXXXXXX</phoneNumber>
```

...But everything I try ends up like one of the following...

```
<phoneNumber />
```

...or...

```
<key>phoneNumber</key>
<value>xxxxxxxxxx</value>
```

...or...

```
<phoneNumber ns1:PIN="XXXX" />
```

...or my personal favourite...

```
<param1><phoneNumber ns1:PIN="XXXX">XXXXXXXXXX</phoneNumber></param1>
```

Comment: Yes, the first request is the hardest one. You need to fiddle a bit. Often other users can not well explain why something worked for them so in the end everybody needs to fiddle a bit. This is also because of [*"The S stands for Simple"*](http://wanderingbarque.com/nonintersecting/2006/11/15/the-s-stands-for-simple/).

Comment: BTW, you should share the WSDL file with your question and the exact errors you get.